# Laravel5 RouteServiceProvider map method not working

Tags: php, laravel, routes

please, could you give me an idea, why my code doesn't work?

I used this tutorial: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website/?page=1 to be able to make my laravel5 site multilanguage, but now it throws, when I try url like this: **smth.com/en** this error: 
**NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 7693:**

Do you have any idea, how to make it working please? Thank you very much :)

CODE:

part of routes.php

```
Route::get('login', [
    'as' => 'login',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@login'
]);
Route::post('login', [
    'as' => 'postLogin',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@authenticate'
]);
```

RouteServiceProvider:

```
// here I add prefix    
public function map(Router $router, Request $request)
    {
        $locale = $request->segment(1);
        $this->app->setLocale($locale);

        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace, 'prefix' => $locale], function($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });
    }


// here is complete language middleware     
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;

    class Language implements Middleware {

        public function __construct(Application $app, Redirector $redirector, Request $request) {
            $this->app = $app;
            $this->redirector = $redirector;
            $this->request = $request;
        }

        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            // Make sure current locale exists.
            $locale = $request->segment(1);

            if ( ! array_key_exists($locale, $this->app->config->get('app.locales'))) {
                $segments = $request->segments();
                $segments[0] = $this->app->config->get('app.fallback_locale');

                return $this->redirector->to(implode('/', $segments));
            }

            $this->app->setLocale($locale);

            return $next($request);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please paste your routes.php file. The most common reason of gettting NotFoundException is no matching route.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Routes are without prefix. Preffix I'm trying to add in RoutesServiceProvider as is written in the link a post. 
I will post you parts of code to my original question.